# comparison-operator overloading one size fits all

Tags: c#

I remember something about an Interface that if implemented it will automatically take care of all the comparison operators so that it's not necessary to implement each one separately. Does anybody remember such a thing?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43721867/5976576

Comment: I see that c++20 has such a proposal https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/spaceship-operator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO there is nothing Out of the Box in .NET that could do that. Operators in C# are defined as static methods so they cannot be shared like methods of `IEnumerable` (via extension methods). Also `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods must be overloaded explicitly (when you provide `==` and `!=` operators), you cannot use extension methods or any other language mechanism to share them across many unrealated classes.

The closes thing you may do is to create custom base class that will implement `IComparable<>` and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, and define on it set of custom operators.

```
public class Base {
    public static bool operator >(Base l, Base r) {
        return true;    
    }

    public static bool operator <(Base l, Base r) {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Derived : Base { }
public class Derived2 : Base { }
```

and then use:

```
    Derived a = new Derived(), b = new Derived();
    bool g = (a > b);


    Derived2 a2 = new Derived2();
    bool g2 = (a2 > b);
```

But that will work only for closely related types...