# Why are the comparison operators not automatically overloaded with IComparable?

Tags: c#, comparison, operator-overloading

When a class is `IComparable`, then we know everything to overload the `<`, `>` and `==` operators due to the `CompareTo` functionality, right? Then why aren't these overloaded automatically?

Take a look at the example below:

```
public class MyComparable : IComparable<MyComparable>
{
    public int Value { get; }
    public MyComparable(int value) { Value = value; }

    public int CompareTo(MyComparable other) => Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
}
```

I was wondering why something like this wouldn't work by default:

```
MyComparable obj1 = new MyComparable(1),
             obj2 = new MyComparable(2);

if (obj1 < obj2) { /*...*/ }
```

We know that `obj1 < obj2 == true` because of our implementation of `CompareTo`, but because the `<` operator is not overloaded, this will not work. *(I know that `obj1.CompareTo(obj2) < 0` will give the desired result, but that's less obvious in most cases.)*

Only when I add the code below to the class, it will work the way I expected:

```
public static bool operator <(MyComparable x, MyComparable y) => x.CompareTo(y) < 0;
public static bool operator >(MyComparable x, MyComparable y) => x.CompareTo(y) > 0;

// And for equality:
public static bool operator !=(MyComparable x, MyComparable y) => !(x == y);
public static bool operator ==(MyComparable x, MyComparable y)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
    if (((object) x == null) || ((object) y == null)) return false;
    return x.CompareTo(y) == 0;
}
```

This is very generic functionality, so what's the reason these comparisons don't work by default on every `IComparable`?

Comment: Most likely because actual result (not in your particular case, but overall) would be confusing, i.e. `class MyComparable : IComparable<MyComparable>,IComparable<int>, IComparable<string>` would be an interesting case. For general "why feature not in language" check out [minus 100 points](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/) article.

Comment: see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8633

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When a class is IComparable, then we know everything to overload the <, > and == operators due to the CompareTo functionality, right?

Yep.

I share your frustration. Your complaint is number nine on my list of ten things that irritate me about C#.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2425867

> Then why aren't these overloaded automatically?

Features are not implemented by default and have to have reasons to remove them.  Rather, features need to be designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped. If one of those things doesn't happen, no feature.

None of those things happened for your desired feature. The feature has been proposed but never got anywhere close to the top of the list of best uses for the language design team's time.

If you want this feature badly enough you can always pitch it at the Roslyn Github forum and maybe it will be implemented someday.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8633) already on the Roslyn Github forum for this feature. It was closed for two reasons:

- First: It might break someone's code if it was not implemented the "obvious" way.
- Second: by default the `==` operator compares by reference changing it to `CompareTo` will break code.

There is a Nuget package that is supposed to do as OP desires, I did not test it. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Exts.Comparisions.Classes.Operators/

Comment: I understand the problems of changing the behaviour of the == operator, but is there any reason that this cannot be implemented for the <, >, <= and >= operators?

Comment: @mrlucks See the above proposal link. Your argument is made over there. I think the final reasoning was the reason that I mentioned first.